# Cytoscape.js style node based on content

Tags: css, cytoscape.js, cytoscape-web

I would like to color my root node a different color than the rest of the nodes on the screen, I have already done some pre-work to identify the value of the root node and have it readily available in a variable. However, in trying to style the graph nothing happens and its been difficult to debug through this.

example:

```
nodes: [{id = 1}, {id=2}]

var startingNode = 1; //root node

$('#cy').cytoscape({
                style: [
                    {
                        selector: 'node',
                        css: {
                            'content': 'data(id)',
                            'background-color': 'red',
                            'color': 'black',
                            'border-width': '1px',
                            'border-color': 'black'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        selector: "node[content = 'startingNode']", 
                        css: {
                            'content': 'data(id)',
                            'background-color': 'purple',
                            'color': 'black',
                            'border-width': '1px',
                            'border-color': 'black'

                        }
                    }]

// more info for cytoscape rendering omitted

});
```

Any input would be helpful!

Thanks,
Paul G.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless, `content` is in the node's `data`, that won't work.  If you have the ID of a node (e.g. `foo`), you can use `#foo` or `[id = 'foo']` as the selector.

Comment: referring to the above example:

`selector: 'node[id = startingNode]'`
 does not work, however:

`selector: 'node[id = "1"]'` does, is the problem the scoping of my variable? And if so any suggestions on an approach?

Comment: You can't reference a variable in a string with JS without either concatenation or the string templating available in ES6.  This might help you: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html

Comment: Awesome, completely forgot about all that.

`selector: 'node[id = "'+startingNode+'"]'`

worked perfectly, thank you for the assistance!